# X-axis Label Gets Cut Off Of Graph

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have in my python script this

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

date_list = ["01/11/2015", "01/12/2015", "01/13/2015", "01/14/2015"]
plt.plot([1,2,3,4], [2,4,6,8])
plt.xticks([1,2,3,4], date_list)
locs, labels = plt.xticks()
plt.setp(labels, rotation=45)
plt.savefig('test.pdf')
```

And it produced a graph that looks like this

[image]

As you can see the x label get cut off and this is not me not fully expanding the graph, I have tried that and it is still cut off. How can I get the whole label on the graph?

Answer (score 14):

Either use:

```
plt.tight_layout()
```

or specifically set the margins, e.g. using `subplots_adjust()`:

> subplots_adjust(left=None, bottom=None, right=None, top=None,
>                     wspace=None, hspace=None)

The first solution with your example results in:

[image]

Comment: `plt.tight_layout()` do the job for me, there is also `pad` argument which can be used to add margin