# text on xlabel is cutted off in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to plot this data:

```
datetime
2021-12-06 00:00:00     40354
2021-12-06 00:05:00     94557
2021-12-06 00:10:00     53314
2021-12-06 00:15:00     91334
2021-12-06 00:20:00     94168
2021-12-06 00:25:00     92049
2021-12-06 00:30:00     89400
2021-12-06 00:35:00     86499
2021-12-06 00:40:00     87517
```

I use

```py
plt.plot(data)
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.axis('tight')
plt.savefig('plot.png')
plt.close()
```

But the x label is cutted off :

[image]

I went through this question [X-axis Label Gets Cut Off Of Graph - Python Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33904163/x-axis-label-gets-cut-off-of-graph-python-matplotlib) and I tried to use `plt.tight_layout()` and `plt.savefig('plot.png', bbox_inches='tight')` but it did not help. Can you help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 

date_t = [str(datetime(2021,12,6,0,item,0,0)) for item in range(0,50,5)]
y_vals = np.random.randint(100,200,len(date_t))

fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,6))
ax.plot(y_vals)
ax.set_xticks(range(len(y_vals)))
ax.set_xticklabels(date_t)
ax.tick_params(axis='x',labelrotation=90)
```

The output is like

[image: test]